# calculation of expiration dates with sql

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

my first time doing a date calculation on my system

[image: HELP ME WITH THIS LOGIC]

as you can see here on my first query how would i say that my expdate table is equal to this current date? then if so msgbox me "your item has expired"

on my second query i wanted to set a msgbox where msgbox me three months before my expdate ?

heres what i tried to do

```
cn.Open()
Dim query As String
query = "Select * from tblmeds where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,`expdate`,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())< 1"
command = New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
readers = command.ExecuteReader

Dim count As Integer
count = 0
While readers.Read
  count = count + 1
End While

cn.Close()

If count = 1 Then
  msgbox "you have a expired items"
else
  "no items are at risk"
```

PS:i am currently using PHPMYADMIN as my database

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code - we can't do anything with an image.  Paste the actual code into your question...

Comment: What database are you using?  Also provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: GETDATE() for MS SQL Server.
current_date for Postgresql.
SYSDATE for Oracle,
NOW() for MySQL

Comment: `DateAdd()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx  (assuming SQL Server) subtract 3 months from expdate and check to see if current date is <= that date.

Comment: @AdrianStanculescu -- CURRENT DATE on DB2

Comment: i will edit my post now

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: see my edited code please. PS im using PHPMYADMIN as my database

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your logic is very useful tho i will apply it and see

Comment: PHPMYADMIN  is not a database.  You are probably using MAriaDB which is a variant of MySQL (neither of which has any relation to MS SQL Server at all)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL SErver...

Subtract 3 months from the expiration date and compare that to the utc date (if multiple timezones are involved) otherwise you could just use getDate()

```
SELECT EXPDATE
FROM tblMeds
WHERE Dateadd(Month, -3,expDate) < = getutcdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change you query to

```
query = "Select count(*) as cnt from tblmeds where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,`expdate`,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())< 1"
```

Then you won't need a look to count the rows, the server can do that which is faster.